# How do i get the Total of a calculated measure removed in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, data-analysis

I calculated some MEASURES for my Power Bi visuals, my measure say "number of internet users" shows up a total of the values in the column. But i wish not to see the total of this measure in the visual.

I have tried to use `selectedvalue()` of Power BI and also `IF(HasOneValue())` but these functions do not accept calculated measures. They are showing up table and columns thus making it "impossible" for me to pass my calculated measure to remove the total.

Please, can I get help on how to over come this challenge? I simply want the Total of this measure "number of internet users" not to show up in Visuals

Comment: Show your sample data with your expected output.

Comment: In most visuals you can turn of the (sub)totals. Have you tried this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use it as an intermediate measure, where you create more complex measures by doing something like CALCULATE([Number of Internet Users], 'Users'[City]="Houston") but don't want the raw measure to show in your measures? If so, right-click on the measure and select 'Hide' from the menu that pops up.